# Angular , When posting form the numeric value coming in quotes which i dont want

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

You can see in the attachment, the cheque number is integer but it is showing as string in the `ts` file, it is dynamic form, I want to send it as numeric value.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Ivo.png)

Comment: Check your input type. Is it text or number?

Comment: its a number....

Comment: Can you post the code of your form and how you assign value to the form element?

Comment: @ArpitAJ Provide some code of .html and .ts for cheque number so that we can help you.

Comment: added html file content, you can see in attachment

Comment: Add component.ts code as well if you are assigning the value to it or doing any other operation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a + before a string numeric converts it into a number.

eg const a: string = '24';

const v:number = +a;

console.log(a,v) // '24' 24
So it's not very clear from your requirement, but somewhere you are getting a text where you expect it to be a number.

So for your control `chequeNo`, you can either do it the dirty way ie

before sending the data ->
const data = this.dynamicForm.value;

data.chequeNo = +data.chequeNo;
`and then use this data to have chequeNo as number`

Or a cleaner

```js
const data =form.value();
for (const key in Object.keys(data)){
if(!isNaN(+data[key])){
data[key] = +data[key]
}
}
```

Comment: I am using dynamic form, so dont know the fields name, this might be with different names.

Comment: Ok,so can we conclude that you want to change all the numeric text fields to numbers?